# MediaCodec returns null for getOutputImage on real devices - Emulator works

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, exoplayer

I'm trying to grab the Image of a Video via the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) using the [getOutputImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getOutputImage(int)) method (Framework used: Exoplayer). I'm NOT using a SurfaceView and every thing else seems fine ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48928528/4584212) is the implementation). On my emulator I get proper Images. On all my real devices (OnePlus One with Android 7.1.1, Honor 8 with Android 7.0, Samsung Galaxy Tab S with Android 6.0.1) I ALWAYS get null as Image. The Video does play however because I can hear the sound. When showing the Image on a SurfaceView, all my real devices also work fine.

I'm slowly going crazy. Can anyone point me into a direction what I might be doing wrong? Or any direction I might debug / test to figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Exoplayer (v.7) uses the MediaCodec with a [DummySurface](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/index.html?com/google/android/exoplayer2/video/DummySurface.html) inside [MediaCodecVideoRenderer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/video/MediaCodecVideoRenderer.html) when configuring the MediaCodec when you don't pass a own Surface to the Exoplayer. **In other words, its probably not a good idea to extract the Image from the MediaCodec when using the Exoplayer because it actually should never work...** (but strangely does on Android 8).